# Consulta varias veces una columna de una misma tabla

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, join

Quisiera saber ¿Cómo puedo extraer, en una consulta en MySQL, un valor varias veces de una misma tabla, relacionándola con una columna de una consulta?

Por ejemplo, tengo la tabla (UUIDEmitidos):

[image]

De la tabla anterior quiero hacer una consulta en la que divida los uuid relacionados que pueden ser 1, 2 0 3, actualmente estoy haciendo la división por el numero largo en caracteres de la relacion que son 36 con un subtring adicional a esa separación quiero arrojar la fecha de cada uno de los uuid relacionados para quedar de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente la consulta la estoy generando:

```
SELECT
UUID,
FECHA UUID,
substring(UUIDEmitidos.UUIDRelacionados,1,36) AS 'UUID RELACIONADO 1',
substring(UUIDEmitidos.UUIDRelacionados,38,36) AS 'UUID RELACIONADO 2',
substring(UUIDEmitidos.UUIDRelacionados,75,36) AS 'UUID RELACIONADO 3'

FROM
UUIDEmitidos
```

Soy un rotundo novato, gracias por su apoyo!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas varios `LEFT JOIN`, prueba así:

```
SELECT u.uuid, u.fechauuid, 
    u.uuidrelacionado1, u1.fechauuid,
    u.uuidrelacionado2, u2.fechauuid, 
    u.uuidrelacionado3, u3.fechauuid
    FROM UUIDEmitidos u
    LEFT JOIN UUIDEmitidos u1 ON u1.uuid=u.uuidrelacionado1
    LEFT JOIN UUIDEmitidos u2 ON u2.uuid=u.uuidrelacionado2
    LEFT JOIN UUIDEmitidos u3 ON u3.uuid=u.uuidrelacionado3;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado David JP, sí funcionó, ahora tengo una pregunta un poco más complicada para mí, actualicé la pregunta añadiendo en la consulta si es posible relacionar una columna de la tabla a una columna de consulta. Saber si es posible que el LEFT JOIN se relacione a las columna substring(UUIDEmitidos.UUIDRelacionados,1,36) AS 'UUID RELACIONADO 1' que sale de la consulta. De antemano agradezco el apoyo

Comment: Sí, puedes conectar por el substring que necesites. Pero tienes que aportar el dataset  con phpmyadmin->Exportar para que pueda ayudarte, ya no es tan sencillo como para sacarlo a partir de una captura de pantalla. No te olvides de poner ejemplos para comprobar el funcionamiento de la consulta